# Cut shapes to half Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to cut shapes in half and create a shape like this(purple shape):

[image]

It is like that with clipped the RoundedRectangle in half.
My current code:

```
struct LeadingClipper: Shape {
    let leading: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).path(in: CGRect(x: rect.size.width - leading,y: 0 , width: rect.size.width, height: leading))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will create the shape you are looking for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let width: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.purple)
            .frame(width: width, height: 50)
            .offset(x: -width / 2)
            .clipped()
            .offset(x: width / 4)
            .frame(width: width / 2)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

## How this works

1. The rounded rectangle shape is created:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
    .fill(Color.purple)
    .frame(width: width, height: 50)
```

[image]

2. Offset the rounded rectangle to the left. Border added in comment to show bounding box of the view - the `offset` modifier does not change the layout of the view, just the visual offset:

```
.offset(x: -width / 2)
//.background(Color.green)
```

[image]

3. Clip the view to its bounding box. This removes everything outside the (temporary) green square:

```
.clipped()
```

[image]

4. Offset the view back to the center. Another `border` in comment to show still the same actual bounding box:

```
.offset(x: width / 4)
//.border(Color.red)
```

[image]

5. Finally, shrink the bounding box to fit this new view which is now half the original width. Another border in comment to show *new* bounding box:

```
.frame(width: width / 2)
//.border(Color.blue)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm very new to SwiftUI. Can you explain how your code works?

Comment: @DuncanC Added some explanation with images, hopefully it helps!

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks. One thing I noticed is that you shift the rounded rect to the left by width/2, and then shift it back by width/4, so the cropped image winds up centered in the specified rectangle. Your comments say that you shift it back, but you actually *center* it.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, I centered it by offsetting it. Offsetting an offset I guess? :p Because it was originally double the size, it took half the offset to center it back again

Comment: You might want to edit your description to say "shift to center the cropped shape" rather than "Offset the view back to the original place" then, since you don't actually put it back in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just getting started with SwiftUI, but I'll try to give you a solution.

It looks like a SwiftUI `Path` has an initializer that takes a `CGPath` as input. It's easy to convert a `UIBezierPath` to a `CGPath`, so I would suggest building your shape using a `UIBezierPath`.

UIBezierPath has an initializer `init(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:)`

So your function would look like this:

```
func path(in: rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 25) -> Path {
    Path(
       UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, 
         byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight],
         cornerRadii: cornerRadius)
       .cgPath)
    )
}
```

(I banged that out in the SO editor. It might have a couple of syntax errors, but the basic approach should work.)

Comment: (That code won't chop your specified rectangle in half; it will create a Path with the specified rectangle where the right corners are rounded and the left corners are square. You'll have to modify it if you want it to create a rectangle that is half as wide as the rectangle you pass into the function.)